# find command not returning results (macOS High Sierra 10.13.4)

Tags: macos, command-line, find

The `find` command is suddenly not returning any results, even for for files I know exist. For example, if I run:

`find . -name calendar.sql`

from a directory I know contains a file called `calendar.sql`, nothing is returned. Surrounding the name of the file with quotes doesn't help.

Not sure what is going on. I've used the command fine in the past.

Comment: Ah, interesting. If I slap `sudo` in front of it, it now works. What gives?

Comment: It appears that somewhere in the directory path there is a subdirectory where you do not have read or execute access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess would be that you now have some other `find` in your path or something has defined a `find` function or alias.

Try `/usr/bin/find . -name calendar.sql` to call it directly. if that works then try `which find` that may discover an errant find in your PATH. Also `alias` will list all aliases and `set | grep find` will find all instances of the word `find` in the currently defined functions.

Comment: In bash, you can use `type find` to see what the shell thinks "find" is (i.e. whether it's an alias, function, builtin, or external command).

Comment: Ugh, at some point in the past I added `alias find="find . -name $1"` to my bash config file.

Comment: We all do it at some stage, @StevieD. I call that a "learning experience" :)